# Recieved error code 16 (UNAUTHENTICATED) from Google Text-to-speech on hourly basis

Tags: c++, linux, google-text-to-speech

I've been running a load test, which keeps sending requests to Google Text-to-Speech. It is noticed that the client would receive a bunch of errors with code 16 (UNAUTHENTICATED) on hourly basis. The errors would last just more than one minute and then everything would be back to normal. Correspondingly I would see some grpc logs like:

> I0418 15:56:42.058182865    4182 call.cc:777]                  1: {"created":"@1555617402.058118998","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1099,"grpc_message":"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","grpc_status":16}
>   I0418 15:56:42.058221929    4182 completion_queue.cc:691]    cq_end_op_for_next(cq=0x1fa9a480, tag=0x1fa96948, error="No Error", done=0x7fba193e52a0, done_arg=0x1fa96a90, storage=0x1fa96a98)

And I'm using grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials.

Comment: This doesn't actually look like an actual error you'd receive from the surface API, but rather an internal log from our code.

Do you have any ill effect on your software itself? If not, this might simply be something to ignore. The debug logs of grpc can be very chatty, and not everything in there are relevant for the end user.

Comment: The error was triggered by the fact that the client system clock was about 15 minutes behind the real time. After ntpd service was enabled, the error is gone. It is about the oauth access token, which would get expired unexpectedly with wrong client system clock.

Comment: Ah, yes! That would do it :-) Clock synchronization is important for auth.